# How can I track the last modified user of a file in an SQL Server 2012 FileTable

Tags: sql-server-2012

Other than through a custom interface to store/fetch files using the old filestream way, is there a way to log which user modified a file opened directly from the share exposed by Sql Server 2012?

Answer (score 1):

Turn on auditing at the file system level. The file system APIs should then capture this information to the Security Event log.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without some type of file watcher application as Windows does not track this information itself.